# how can i change step of index in forEach method at javascript?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I am new in javascript , I don't know how to change step of index with forEach method!

for instance I need to print elements which at even indices .
I do this with for loop as this :

```
for (var i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i+=2)
{ 
   console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

how can I do this with forEach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't skip indexes with `.forEach()` method but you can check if the current index number is even or not. If it is, print the array element at that index, otherwise do nothing.

```
arr.forEach((num, idx) => {
   if (idx % 2 == 0) {
      console.log(num);
   }
});
```

`.forEach()` method is different as compared to a `for` loop. Using `for` loop, you control the loop variable that is used as the array index when iterating over the array using a `for` loop.

`.forEach()` method doesn't gives you that control, it just allows you to specify a callback function which `.forEach()` method will call with 4 arguments:

- Current array element
- Index of the current array element
- Whole array over on which `.forEach()` method was called
- Value to use as `this` inside the callback function

Using `.forEach()`, you don't need to worry about initializing the loop variable, loop termination condition and how loop variable should be incremented.

To know more about `.forEach()` method, see: [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

Callback function you pass to the `forEach` method takes the index in its second argument:

```
arr.forEach((item, i) => {
    if (i % 2 === 0)  // only even indices
        console.log(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    
    arr.forEach((num, i) => {
       if (i % 2 == 0) {
          console.log(num);
       }
    });
```