# Are there any cases JavaScript’s forEach works where a for loop doesn’t?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

JavaScript’s `Array.prototype.forEach` is usually significantly slower than a `for` loop. This is because `forEach` includes extra checks that a `for` loop normally doesn’t have. Are there any cases where a `forEach` loop works (because of these checks) where a `for` loop doesn’t?

To be clear, I am not asking *why* `for` is faster than `forEach`. I am asking if the extra checks in `forEach` are ever useful.

Comment: what extra checks are you talking about? In most practical cases, you are unlikely to see major performance differences in your application between `for` and `forEach`.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155280/why-is-native-javascript-array-foreach-method-significantly-slower-than-the-stan). It shows the extra checks in the `forEach` implementation.

Comment: I am aware there are rarely major performance differences; I'm just curious about the use cases of `forEach` as opposed to `for`.

Comment: Array methods are preferred over for loops because they express their intent more clearly. You can read the following articles: [loops-are-evil.md](https://gist.github.com/robotlolita/7643014) and [Can we say that the "for loop" will be the new "goto,” given the increasing popularity of functional programming?](https://www.quora.com/Can-we-say-that-the-for-loop-will-be-the-new-goto-%E2%80%9D-given-the-increasing-popularity-of-functional-programming/answer/Tikhon-Jelvis?share=1)

Comment: One thing that `forEach()` can't do is [`skip array indexes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64100018/how-can-i-change-step-of-index-in-foreach-method-at-javascript)

Comment: @Yousaf You can get around that by checking the index inside the function, doing a noop. To emulate a `break` you'd have to set a flag. You'd still have to iterate over every element though. If you need to break out of a nested loop, you'd need to return a magic value.

Comment: @MoritzRoessler yes you can get around that but still you aren't skipping indexes. And also you can't stop `.forEach()` from executing from start till end whereas a `for` loop can be terminated using the `break` keyword.

Comment: @Yousaf Yes, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several differences between forEach and using a for loop

The most obvious is how they deal with sparse arrays. forEach wont try to run the callback if it hits an empty array element but for will and the array item will give undefined.

On the other side, you can’t just break out of a forEach as you can a for loop.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach for further details.

Answer (score 2):

`forEach()` skip empty elements (holes) in the array, `for` do not.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `for` loop as slow as you want by changing the traditional increment to a more complex operation. It also has to do an inequality check during each iteration, so that is another opportunity to introduce delays, by using a more complex condition.

`forEach` is very specific, but `for` can offer more flexibility.

Comment: Right. But are there any scenarios where `forEach` can do something that `for` can't?

Comment: No, and that's confirmed by the polyfill answer you linked to. And those checks happen up-front, not inside the loop.